# Processing RPAREN error

Tags: processing

```java
class PosterA{ 
  color bgC; 
  color imgC; 
  color titleC; 
  color bodyC; 
  color elementC; 
  color PriceC; 
  PVector titlePos = (0,0); 
  PVector bodyPos = (0,0); 
  PVector pricePos= (0,0); 
  PVector elementPos = (0,0); 
  PFont font; 
}
```

It keeps on telling me that there's an error on the comma, that it expects a a right parentheses instead, but that makes no sense to me? Am I assigning the PVector values wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This won't work:

```java
PVector elementPos = (0,0);
```

This is not valid syntax. You need to call the `PVector` constructor by using the `new` keyword along with the class name, followed by the parameters inside of parenthesis (your `(0,0)` part).

In other words, you need to do this instead:

```java
PVector elementPos = new PVector(0,0);
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://www.processing.org/reference/PVector.html).